How to prevent cpack with productbuild from modifying and un-signing binaries?
I'm using the productbuild CPACK generator to build a .pkg installer from my binary (actually a bundle containing a shared lib). The binary bundle is built with cmake (Ninja generator) and is properly signed using a custom POST_BUILD step.
But cpack (which I run as cpack --config build/CPackConfig.cmake) apparently runs install_name_tool to update RPATH or something, which invalidates the signature, before packaging it up into the installer.
CPack: Create package using productbuild
CPack: Install projects
CPack: - Install project: myprod []
CPack: -   Install component: mycompany_myproduct
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: 
warning: changes being made to the file will invalidate the code signature in: /Users/garyo/mycompany/myproduct/_CPack_Packages/Darwin/productbuild/Myprod-v1/mycompany_myproduct/Library/Application Support/Mycompany/./myprod.plugin/Contents/MacOS/myprod
CPack: Create package
CPack: -   Building component package: /Users/garyo/mycompany/myproduct/_CPack_Packages/Darwin/productbuild/Myprod-v1/Contents/Packages/Myprod-v1-mycompany_myproduct.pkg
CPack: - package: /Users/garyo/mycompany/myproduct/Myprod-v1.pkg generated.


As far as I can tell, there's no hook for me to re-sign the binary before cpack finishes running productbuild, so I can't create a properly signed installer (which needs properly signed code).
Is there some way to tell cpack to not run install_name_tool?

This probably needs a [mcve] that shows how your signing is being done.

I seem to have a workaround: set(CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH TRUE) causes cmake not to set RPATH in my binaries, and for whatever reason, that allows cpack to avoid calling install_name_tool and breaking the signature. It works for me, anyway, since my plugin doesn't need any RPATH settings.

Post that as an answer instead of a comment.
